# AOC e1549Fwu USB screen does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, monitor, external-monitor

I can't get my AOC e1549Fwu USB monitor to work on Ubuntu 16.04 (Dell Inspiron 5548 laptop). I have tried the following drivers:

- Driver that comes with Ubuntu
- [DisplayLink drivers](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu)
- [displaylink-debian](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian)

All of those drivers produce garbled output, such as only the mouse pointer appears and the rest of the screen is full of multi-color artifacts. Attaching and detaching the USB screen while the laptop is powered on also causes the O.S. to freeze (requires a hard reboot), unless the USB monitor is disabled in Unity's Display settings.

There is also a HDMI screen connected to the laptop, which works normally.

Additional info:

```
uname -a
Linux bruno-Inspiron-5548 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 
21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 17e9:4107 DisplayLink 

dmesg
[ 2390.869937] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 2390.981941] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2391.217988] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=4107
[ 2391.217991] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2391.217993] usb 2-1: Product: e1649Fwu
[ 2391.217994] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[ 2391.217995] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: FJB42IA000842
[ 2391.220470] hid-generic 0003:17E9:4107.0007: hiddev0,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Device [DisplayLink e1649Fwu] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[ 2392.237167] [drm] vendor descriptor length:17 data:17 5f 01 00 15 05 00 01 03 00 04
[ 2392.316377] udl 2-1:1.0: fb1: udldrmfb frame buffer device
[ 2392.316383] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[ 2392.316385] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[ 2392.316387] [drm] Initialized udl on minor 2

lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
  Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
  Kernel driver in use: i915
  Kernel modules: i915
```

Already tried connecting it to different USB ports.

Thanks in advance.